# reset solution number at each chapter

Tags: pdftex, answers

With the answer package I'am be able to reset the exo counter by chapter with

```
\newcounter{exocounter}[chapter]
```

note it's not gone by answers. I using the exocounter to define automatically each number of question in environment {exo}

I'would like the same with all solution.

precisely I would like the following title

```
    Solution exercice N°1 section 1.1
    Solution exercice N°2 section 1.2
    Solution exercice N°1 section 2.1
    Solution exercice N°2 section 2.1
    Solution exercice N°3 section 2.1
    Solution exercice N°1 section 3
    Solution exercice N°2 section 3.1
    Solution exercice N°3 section 3.1
```

Do you thing is there a automatic solution?
Obviouly I don't wonder a manual solution with a number by every solution part, and only one chapter for all solution.

Because I have only one solution chapter I understand the solucounter never reseted

With the following code it's not running like I would like.

```
\documentclass{book}
%% test_answers.tex
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}%pour un document en français
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.68,1.0,0.18}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{xargs}    
\usepackage[xcolor]{changebar} % pour barre verticale sur le côté   
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usepackage{hyperref}%rend actif les liens, références croisée, toc, ...
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,french,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]%
{\begin{list}{}{%
            \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
            \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
        }\item }%
    {\end{list}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------- version solution séparées à  la fin
\usepackage{answers}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% --------------------- Environnement Exercice OK --------------------------------
%compteur d'exo côté question remis automatiquement à zéro à chaque nouveau chapitre
\newcounter{exocounter}[chapter]
%compteur de solution d'exercice qui va suivre au même rythme les questions
\newcounter{solucounter}[chapter]

\newenvironment{ex}[1]
{\begin{trivlist}
        \stepcounter{exocounter}
        \item {\tikz[baseline=-0.25em]
            \node[%
            rectangle,%
            rounded corners=2pt,%
            fill=orange,%
            inner sep=3pt,%
            outer sep=0pt,%
            align = center,%
            text width=75mm]
            {%
                \normalsize
                \bfseries
                \color{black}
                Exercice section \thesection-Numéro \theexocounter :
            };} #1 } 
    {\end{trivlist}}


\Newassociation{solution}{Soln}{ans}

\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]
{\begin{trivlist}
        \stepcounter{solucounter}
        \item {\tikz[baseline=-0.25em]
            \node[%
            rectangle,%
            rounded corners=2pt,%
            fill=mygreen,%
            inner sep=3pt,%
            outer sep=0pt,%
            align = center,%
            text width=75mm] %85 si je sais corriger le reste
            {%
                \normalsize
                \bfseries
                \color{black}
                %Solution exercice section \thesection-Numéro \theexocounter :
                Solution exercice N°\thesolucounter \hspace{1 mm}section #1\hspace{1 mm} % 
            };} } 
    {\end{trivlist}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}    
\mainmatter% corps du document

\Opensolutionfile{ans}[reponse]

\chapter{chapitre essai }   

\section{section 1}

    %----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
    \begin{ex} {personnalisation du travail d'impression }%{1}
        % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
        \label{ex-exo-demo-1} %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*}}
        \lipsum[1]

        \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-1} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-1}}
        \begin{solution}{personnalisation du travail d'impression   page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-1}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

            \label{solex-exo-demo-1}

            \lipsum[1]

        \end{solution}
    \end{ex}
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{section 2}

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {Travail d'impression}%{2}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-exo-demo-2} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*****}}
    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-2} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-2}}
    \begin{solution}{travail d'impression page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-2}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-exo-demo-2}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{chapitre essai suite}

\section{section 1}

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {personnalisation du travail d'impression }%{3}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-exo-demo-3} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*}}
    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-3} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-3}}
    \begin{solution}{personnalisation du travail d'impression   page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-3}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-exo-demo-3}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {Découpage d'impression}%{4}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-exo-demo-4} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*****}}
    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-4} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-4}}
    \begin{solution}{Découpage d'impression page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-4}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-exo-demo-4}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {analyse d'un fichier meson.build}{1}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-passurvie-1} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-passurvie-1} page~\pageref{solex-passurvie-1}}
    \begin{solution}{analyse d'un fichier meson.build page~\pageref{ex-passurvie-1}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-passurvie-1}   

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{chapitre essai suite}

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {personnalisation du travail d'impression }%{3}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-exo-demo-5} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*}}
    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-5} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-5}}
    \begin{solution}{personnalisation du travail d'impression   page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-5}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-exo-demo-5}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{section 2}

%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {Découpage d'impression}%{4}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-exo-demo-6} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}*****}}
    \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-exo-demo-6} page~\pageref{solex-exo-demo-6}}
    \begin{solution}{Découpage d'impression page~\pageref{ex-exo-demo-6}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-exo-demo-6}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------modele exercice le top dernier Version 5----------------
\begin{ex} {analyse d'un fichier meson.build}{1}
    % sous -entendu exercice sur .....
    \label{ex-passurvie-9} %saut de ligne nécessaire

    \marginpar {\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{ Difficulté\hspace{1 mm}***}}

        \lipsum[1]

    \textbf{Solution exercice \ref{ex-passurvie-9} page~\pageref{solex-passurvie-9}}
    \begin{solution}{analyse d'un fichier meson.build page~\pageref{ex-passurvie-9}}  %saut de ligne nécessaire

        \label{solex-passurvie-9}   

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{solution}
\end{ex}


\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\chapter{Solution des exercices}
\input{reponse}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not simply use a cross-reference rather than an independent counter?

Comment: bernard could you explain in more detail how do you thing to use cross-reference? In this case I would like to have the same number pour question and answer

Comment: More precisely, if your exercises are  numbered, add a  `\label{exrc:n}`, say, at the beginning of the environment. Then, to number the solution, add a `\ref{exrc:n}` to have the same number in the solution environment. As I don't use the answer package, I can give you only the general idea.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's interesting, but my target is to numbering each solution not by section and numbering with **exocounter**

Comment: For the first point, if the exercises are numbered continuously, the cross references will be  too. You also can ask that the exocounter varies as  the exercise counter (as I don't know the details, maybe I'm saying silly things).

Comment: I understand nobody can help me, never mind. I change my context and keep a continuous numbering

Comment: Actually, I've just seen you don't use the `answer` package, you make your own lists yourself?